# How can you create a non-empty CharField in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple model which looks like this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=False)
```

I would expect this to throw an integrity error, but it does not:

```
group = Group() # name is an empty string here
group.save()
```

How can I make sure that the name variable is set to something non-empty? I.e to make the database reject any attempts to save an empty string?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/) in this case, your `name` will be stored as an empty string, because the `null` field option is False by default. if you want to define a custom default value, use the `default` field option.

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='somevalue')
```

On this page, you can see that the `blank` is not database-related.

**Update:**

You should override the clean function of your model, to have custom validation, so your model def will be:

```
class Group(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
  def clean(self):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    if self.name == '':
        raise ValidationError('Empty error message')
```

Or you can replace `ValidationError` to something else. Then before you call `group.save()` call `group.full_clean()` which will call `clean()`

Other validation related things are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#id1).

Comment: I see what you mean. What I would really like is to reject any non-empty strings..

Comment: I see, so you want to validate the model. Than I think you should use group.[full_clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#id1) before `group.save()`. But I've never used it. :)

Comment: One way to avoid needing to ensure `full_clean()` is called is to use the `Charfield(default=None)`. This will raise `IntegrityError` instead of `ValidationError`

Comment: @DanH DanH's comment should be the true answer to this question. thank you.

Answer (score 30):

another option that doesn't require you to manually call `clean` is to use this:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default=None)
```

- `blank` will prevent an empty string to be provided in the admin or using a form or serializer (most cases). However as pointed out in the comments, this unfortunately does not prevent things like `model.name = ""`  (manually setting blank string)
- `default=None` will set name to None when using something like `group = Group()`, thus raising an exception when calling `save`

Comment: "blank will prevent an empty string to be provided in your model". This is false. It only prevents empty strings to be passed in the admin or anywhere a proper form or serializer is used. It doesn't prevent `Model.objects.create(name="")` or `model.name = ""; model.save()`.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I'll update my answer

Comment: And how would be the best way to not pass any empty string?

Comment: blank is by default set to False.  No need to set it again..won't even reflect in the migration..https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/

Comment: sure, but in cases like this, I prefer to set it explicitly, because it is very intentional `blank=False, default=None` go together in my mind. personal preference

Comment: `null=False, blank=False, default=None` work fine, but do not know is this django way to do it

Answer (score 12):

Or you can simply use `MinLengthValidator` with a 1-char minimum:

```
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator

class Company(BaseModel):
    """Company"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                            validators=[MinLengthValidator(1)])
```

Comment: Thanks for your elegant solution, it helped me a lot!

Comment: Could you use `validators=[bool]`? `bool(value)` would return false for anything falsey, so empty string, None, etc. Although wouldn't work if zero numeric, empty list, etc. are valid.

Comment: This will not work when you save a model using instance.save() or model.create(). Only works when using ModelForm. Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run

Answer (score 9):

I spent a long time looking for the best solution for this simple (and old) problem, And as of Django 2.2, there is actually a really simple answer, so I'll write it here in case someone still encounters the same problem:

Since Django 2.2, we can define [CheckConstraints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint), so it's easy to define a non-empty string constraint:

```py
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(check=~models.Q(title=""), name="non_empty_title")
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Django’s validation system assumes that all fields are required,unless you mention that its ok to leave it blank..

Have you registered the class in Admin ? does it show errors when you leave it blank ??

[image: Django krishna]

Comment: I am not using the Admin interface, but it looks like blank=True only has effect there. I would like the system to reject blank fields from anywhere..