# Django unclear behaviour on missed values on model initialization

Tags: django, model

I have a postgres Database and a model with a field as blank=False and null=True.
Let's say:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    param1 = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    param2 = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, null=False)
```

Now, when I am creating a model like this:

```
m = MyModel(param1=val1, param2=val2)
```

it basically won't raise any exception for `info` field on saving. Even more, it will keep an empty value for `info` in the database after using `save` method.

**UPDATED**
When instantiating the model like this:
`m = MyModel(param1=val1, param2=val2, info=None)`
saving will raise an exception in that case

Any suggestions why does it happen? In my opinion if I miss to add a value in the model initialization, it should be at least assumed as `None`, but it's not. I googled that and couldn't find an specific answer for that. But, found that only `full_clean()` model method performs checking and raises exceptions like these:

```
ValidationError: {'info': ['This field cannot be blank.'], 'owner': ['This field cannot be blank.']}
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Did you remember to run migrations after you made that change

Comment: Damilola, yes I did... but unfortunately it allows me to initialize the Instance while skipping to refer other params. As I have mentioned, you could write like: 
```MyModel(param1=val1, param2=val2, info=None)``` and in this case it will raise the exception. But if I just remove info=None, it won't. That's what I can't understand. I was thinking that Django should assume that missing any argument to the constructor will be interpreted at least as None. Am I clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after researching I came up with this answer:
First of all, `blank` stands only for form validation, and `null` for DB validation ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#null)). As well, Django always assume the empty value for a missing parameter, but with a little bit different behavior for those field types.

The key difference is that for:

- Char fields - it uses an empty string (which is `''`), the default Django implementation. So if Django sees that there is a missing parameter, it won't pass None for that type of field, since NULL are not being recommended to be stored in DB for char fields. ( [details here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/07/25/django-tip-8-blank-or-null.html) )
- Other fields - it uses an empty value (which is `None`). So Django sees that there is a missing parameter, it will assume it's None. But since the database restriction null=False, it will raise the exception.

So the conclusion is that only non-charfields that are being supposed to use database constraint `null=False` - are being checked on `save` method for missing params by raising exceptions.

Now if you wanna raise exceptions for Charfields as well, you need to use `full_clean` (used by forms) that will tell you what type of field can't be blank (or missing). So in the end, the right way is to use `blank=False` and then `full_clean` to detect missing Charfields. Or/And, [you can override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6940976/4271452) the model`s `clean()` method if have some additional logic to those fields.

Comment: Another way to force the `IntegrityError` to be raised upon saving/creating objects, is by explicitly setting `default=None` on the `CharField`, *in addition to* `null=False` and `blank=False`.

Answer (score -1):

```
info = models.CharField('Facts and features', max_length=1024)
```

Comment: Could you please be more explicit in your explanation? As far as I know, django model has by default blank=False and null=False. So what's that ?